# How to make less empty space between Basemap subplots when using plt.subplot2grid()

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, subplot

I have 5 maps I am trying to plot in one figure. I would like them to be laid out like

```
1 2 3
 4 5
```

To do this, I tried to follow the answer given here:
[Position 5 subplots in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26767281/position-5-subplots-in-matplotlib)

This gives me the correct layout, but there is a ton of empty space left between the subplots.

```
#S,W,N,E Bounds
lonMin = 119
lonMax = 124
latMin = 12
latMax = 19

m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=lonMin,llcrnrlat=latMin,urcrnrlon=lonMax,urcrnrlat=latMax, projection = 'cea', resolution = 'i')

fig = plt.figure()
axes = [plt.subplot2grid(shape=(2,6), loc=(0,0), colspan=2),
        plt.subplot2grid((2,6), (0,2), colspan=2),
        plt.subplot2grid((2,6), (0,4), colspan=2),
        plt.subplot2grid((2,6), (1,1), colspan=2),
        plt.subplot2grid((2,6), (1,3), colspan=2)]
for i in range(5):
    m.ax = axes[i]
    m.drawcoastlines()
fig.suptitle('Title', fontsize = 20, fontweight = 'bold')
```

[image]

How can I reduce the spacing between the subplots?

EDIT:
The problem appears to somehow be tied to putting Basemaps in the plot. If I comment out the `m.drawcoastlines()` call, the axes look like this, which is fine:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

First of all you may try to call [`plt.tight_layout()`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.subplots_adjust) to  adjust spacing between subplots to minimize the overlaps.

Another way is to use [`subplots_adjust`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.subplots_adjust) to set all spaces manually like

```
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=.1) # height spaces
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=.1) # width spaces
```

These functions affect all subplots. If you need more control use GridSpec.

Comment: Neither of these did the trick. plt.tight_layout() got rid of the surrounding blank space but not the space between the plots (and it also made the figures overlap with the title). And fig.subplots_adjust() didn't change anything at all.

Comment: Nevermind....I got `subplots_adjust()` to work, but only by setting the hspace/wspace values to a small negative number, for some reason...