# How to subplot 5 figures in 2 X 3 subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot 5 figures, in a subplot grid of 2 x 3 figures.

How to do this?

There would be an extra empty grid for the 6th subplot.  I want to avoid that.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how to ask a good question.

Comment: You can remove an axes via `ax.remove()`.

Comment: Try using this post as reference and produce a MWE : Minimal Working Example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26767281/position-5-subplots-in-matplotlib

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Position 5 subplots in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26767281/position-5-subplots-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SO! This question has been answered before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26767281/position-5-subplots-in-matplotlib) but I'll offer an alternate solution using `gridspec`

Here's 5 axes with a gap:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

fig = plt.figure()
spec = mpl.gridspec.GridSpec(ncols=3, nrows=2)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(spec[0,0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(spec[0,1])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(spec[0,2])
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(spec[1,0])
ax5 = fig.add_subplot(spec[1,1])
```

[image: gap layout]

Here's a more balanced 5 plot layout:

```
fig = plt.figure()
spec = mpl.gridspec.GridSpec(ncols=6, nrows=2) # 6 columns evenly divides both 2 & 3

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(spec[0,0:2]) # row 0 with axes spanning 2 cols on evens
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(spec[0,2:4])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(spec[0,4:])
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(spec[1,1:3]) # row 0 with axes spanning 2 cols on odds
ax5 = fig.add_subplot(spec[1,3:5])
```

[image: better layout]